# NameError: global name 'INSERT' is not defined

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

Trying my hand at Tkinter and just want to add a simple `Text` field. I've been able to add `Entry`, `Button` and `Label` but `Text` causes an issue. Here is what I have for `Text`:

```
import Tkinter

class myapp_tk(Tkinter.Tk):
    def __init__(self,parent):
        Tkinter.Tk.__init__(self,parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.initialize()

    def initialize(self):
        self.grid()

        self.about = Tkinter.Text(self)
        self.about.insert(INSERT, "Hello World!")

        self.about.grid(row=0, column=0)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    myapp = myapp_tk(None)
    myapp.title("My First App!")
    myapp.mainloop()
```

Error received:

`NameError: global name 'INSERT' is not defined`

I've altered the script heading to include `from Tkinter import *` which will force it, but I am curious as to why it doesn't work without that change.

Comment: much like `Tkinter.Tk` and `Tkinter.Text`, you'll need `Tkinter.INSERT`. if you dont use a `from ... *` import

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`INSERT` is a constant defined in `Tkinter`, so you also need to precede it with `Tkinter.` (given your code), that is you need to do:

```
self.about.insert(Tkinter.INSERT, "Hello World!")
```

In general, if you import a module `A` as `import A`, then to call a function or variable `x` from `A` you always need to do `A.x`.

Answer (score 1):

`INSERT` is a Tkinter name, so you'd need `Tkinter.INSERT`.

It's good practice to avoid "star" imports - doing a star import with Tkinter loads over a hundred names into the global namspace, which is messy and a recipe for name collisions.

You can make things less verbose by doing the import like this:

```
import Tkinter as tk
```

Then you can do things like `tk.INSERT` and `tk.Button`, etc.

Another benefit of the `as tk` form is that it makes it easier to migrate your code to Python 3, or to write code that runs on both 2 and 3; the module name in Python 3 is all lowercase: `tkinter`.